How to store relationships in geopackage with QGIS
How can I store relationship in GeoPackage with QGIS and how does it function?
It is hard to find an example in the help program.

in QGIS Project>Relations https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/49504

Was expecting to see the relation in the display. If you can, clarify with example.

Can you clarify what you mean? - The relationships show in the browser as shown above in the link.

I'm not able to attach a picture. The goal is a classic. It is to establish a relationship between an alphanumeric table and a geographic table (between foreign key and primary key), save this relationship in the geopackage and visualize it when clicking on the layer, however, this does not happen because it does not illustrate the relationship, it is as if it were not make the relationship even after having created it, through the QGIS browser (by clicking on the database in geopackage...).
Also, I don't konw how you created so many relations. I only have one cardinality option: many-to-many

You can manage the one to many relationship outside of QGIS, for example in DB Browser for SQLite (-> https://sqlitebrowser.org/). After that the Parent-Child relationship is recognized as a database relationship and you will see it in the QGIS Browser:


Thanks for the help. So it has to be with a 3rd party program.
